# ASPX Files are not showing up

Tags: asp.net, iis-7, master-pages

I am running into a bazar issue...

The ASPX pages are part of a MasterPage project.  The main site opens up using Default.aspx, but no links that reference any ASPX pages on the site will work... even if I try calling them fully qualified with the site name.  So I'm not sure if it is a problem in how I have IIS set up or if it is some anomaly with MasterPages.  It is a new ASPX.Net Web Application using Visual Studio 2013.  I have never ran into this in previous versions of Visual Studio.

Below is a test HTML file. The first 2 links do not work, the last HTML link works fine.  I have tried calling the links from them main Default.aspx using ~/test.aspx or test.aspx.  When hovering over the link, it shows the link correctly, but when clicking on the link, it says page not found.  On the page not found error, it does not show any .aspx extension.  The app runs fine in my dev environment, it is only when running this on the server. (IIS 7 running on Win Server 2008)

```
    <HTML>This is a Link test</HTML>
    </BR>
    <a href="www.MySite.com/Test.aspx" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg">ASPX link does not work &raquo;</a></BR>
    <a href="Test.aspx" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg">ASPX Link does not work &raquo;</a></BR>
    <a href="Test2.html" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg">HTML Link works &raquo</a>
```

By default, it uses ViewSwitcher and Bootstrap, I'm not sure what these are and if they may be doing things behind the scenes to make links operate differently.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out it was just a web.config setting that was preventing the pages from opening.

```
<system.webServer>
   <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
</system.webServer>
```